# Find Likelihood function of $\theta$ for $f(y|\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta + 1}$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

So, I know the likelihood function is the product of the density from $1$ to $n$. So then it would be $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{2\theta + 1}\right)^n$. I just want to see if I am doing that correctly.

Comment: So $y$ is the random variable and $\theta$ is the parameter?

Comment: Yes I am sorry, Y is a random variable from uniform distribution, and f(y|theta) is its density function

Comment: yes, it looks right.